# Answer Only RSS feed for a user

Tags: feature-request, support, feed

Is there an RSS feed like https://serverfault.com/feeds/user/2561 but for answers *only*, for a specified user?

Comment: You could probably do something with [IFTTT](http://ifttt.com). Use the [feed](http://ifttt.com/feed) channel with the "New feed item matches" trigger. (I'd search by "Answer by {your display name}". Then use whatever channel matches the best way to get it on to your blog. (There are channels for WordPress, Blogger, Medium, Tumblr, and Weebly.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Currently, no.

But, if you *really* want to stalk somebody, don't you want to know *everything* that they do?

Comment: It would be for myself, put the feed on my blog.

Answer (score 14):

There is now. I have created an application called [Stack2RSS](https://stackapps.com/questions/1599/stack2rss-a-json-to-rss-conversion-service) that converts API requests into RSS feeds.

A feed that fetches all of a user's answers looks something like this:

> `http://stack2rss.quickmediasolutions.com/2.2/users/{id}/answers?site={site}`

Example that fetches all of the answers posted by user #1 (Jeff Atwood) on SuperUser:

> http://stack2rss.quickmediasolutions.com/2.2/users/1/answers?site=superuser

Comment: +1 that's an awesome app! Is there a reason why these RSS feeds can't seem to work in the chatroom feeds?

Comment: Application has now been moved to http://stack2rss.quickmediasolutions.com/. Links updated (once they come through moderation).

Answer (score 3):

You can take the regular user feed, and then filter it using one of the rss filtering websites, for example, https://siftrss.com/

Answer (score 2):

Parse their answer-source:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/api/useranswers.html?userid=130154&page=1&pagesize=10&sort=recent

That will show you their most recent 10. Change pagesize to increase count.

Answer (score -5):

Next best thing/workaround is to bookmark the user's recent tab and refresh every now and then. Now you'll not only be able to see their movements on answering questions, but when they comment and if they edit a post as well.