# Can I get Stackoverflow's user feeds, about only the answers

Tags: feature-request, answers, users, feed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Answer Only RSS feed for a user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14183/answer-only-rss-feed-for-a-user)

I tried to get feed of the top rankers.
But there were too many feeds(because of their comments feed)
It's annoying me.

I want to get feeds of their **answer**.
Is it possible?

Comment: Discussions about stackoverflow should be done at
http://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: I think you should ask this question here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/?

Comment: haha Dan, you're 2sec quicker ;-)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean; the user feed doesn't include comments.

Comment: It includes comments.

Comment: Oops, you're correct, they're just not in chronological order with the other posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible using a small application I created called [Stack2RSS](http://stack2rss.quickmediasolutions.com/) that converts API requests into RSS feeds.

Example (shows all answers by [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) on Stack Overflow):

> http://stack2rss.quickmediasolutions.com/2.2/users/22656/answers?site=stackoverflow

Comment: @George: It doesn't work since a couple of weeks ago. Your app make url like this. http://stackapps/questions/2439 .com is trimmed.

Comment: @Benjamin: There was an upgrade a couple of weeks ago. Can I please have the exact URL of the feed that is no longer working?

Comment: @George: http://quickmediasolutions.com/stack2rss/stackoverflow/users/17034/answers?body=true The feed works fine. But when I click the feed title to jump real page(stackoverflow.com) in Google Reader, it jump to wrong URL.

Comment: @Benjamin: Ah, you're right. I'll get this fixed - in the meantime, you can change `stackoverflow` to `stackoverflow.com` to make it work.

Comment: @George: Anything works anymore. What happened?

Comment: @Benjamin: Sorry about that. It's working now.

Comment: @George: Everything is fine again. Thanks.

Comment: When I add more users now, I get `No Content` at my feed reader. I have to click the link and should jump SO to read the answers. But for the users I registered long time ago, the feed get the answer's *all content*. So I can read them at my google reader conveniently. Why is it?

Comment: @Benjamin: Can you please provide me with the URL for the feed you are using?

Comment: http://quickmediasolutions.com/stack2rss/stackoverflow/users/151292/answers *No content*

Comment: http://quickmediasolutions.com/stack2rss/stackoverflow/users/17034/answers?body=true *Full content*

Comment: I have guessed what is the problem, though. It's the query string, right?

Comment: Your application added the query string `body=true` by default long time ago, but not anymore I think.

Comment: @Benjamin: I honestly can't remember if it used to add `body=true` or not. But it definitely does not add it now. You will need to explicitly add that parameter.

Comment: Okay fine. I know what the problem was now. I fixed all address missing query string. I'm using user app very well, everyday. Thank you.

Comment: 404 does not exist? What happend?

Comment: @Benjamin: I've corrected the links.

Comment: Thank you! Works well.

Comment: Sorry about that - Stack2RSS is now hosted by Stack Exchange and a lot of posts here have outdated links to the older version.

Comment: Any new link please?

Answer (score 0):

This has been [asked once before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14183/answer-only-rss-feed-for-a-user), but I don't see it having been responded to by an admin.

Comment: @Benjamin: My answer provides a solution.