# Is it possible to compare the activity level of Stack Overflow users?

Tags: feature-request, support

I'd like to compare users according to how frequently they view the site. On Stack Overflow, is it possible to view a list of users, sorted by their likelihood of being online (so that I can tell whether or not they are likely to respond to other users' posts)? (It would be possible, at least in theory, to determine the likelihood of a user being online. This could be determined by the number of times that a user had accessed the site in the last day, month, week, or year).

If I wanted to respond to one of the users who had closed a question (to determine exactly why the question had been closed), I would want to respond to the user who was online most often. However, there's currently no way to compare the activity level of multiple users at-a-glance.

Also, there's [a related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4445/is-there-a-way-to-identify-whether-users-are-online-or-not) that discusses the possibility of determining whether or not a user is currently online.

Comment: Why would you want to know the likelihood of someone being online at a certain time? Since you posted this as a [feature-request], you should include at least some minimal explanation of how this would be a useful feature for the community.

Comment: @Yannis As explained above, I want to do this so that I can determine whether or not a user is likely to respond to the posts of other users.

Comment: Well I'll upvote you, but I'm not sure exactly how good such a feature would really be.. We could perhaps have a participation page (like on site metas).. I don't think that would be bad..

Comment: @AndersonGreen The reputation graph on a users profile might help you tell. And the activity tab.

Comment: @Seth Still, the activity tab doesn't make it possible to compare the activity level of multiple users at-a-glance.

Comment: @AndersonGreen You explain why you want the feature, but not why that would be useful. If you post a comment on someone's question, for example, they'll respond to you the next time they are online. Why does it matter when that'll be? Would you refrain from posting the comment if you knew they are (probably) not online right now?

Comment: The only use case for this I can think about is stalking.

Comment: @nhahtdh I don't really see how it would enable stalking. If I wanted to respond to one of the users who had closed a question (when multiple users had voted to close the question), I would want to respond to the user who was online most often.

Comment: See also this [Q&A](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/14183/163188).

Comment: @AndersonGreen Close voters will _not_ get notified for `@username` comments, unless they've posted at least one comment in the question. And that's by design, unless someone showed that they care to participate in a discussion (by actually participating in it), there's no reason to spam their inbox. The same goes for chat, if a person hasn't been in a chat room in a couple of days, `@username` messages will never reach them.

Comment: @AndersonGreen: Depending on the implementation, you will know the active time of the other person (day of week, time of day, or how obsessive the person is with the site in general) - I don't think I want to show these information. The time that the user last visited the site and the answer/question statistics should more or less reflects the activity level.

Comment: Define "activity level"

Comment: @KnightswhosayNi I already defined it. I mentioned in the original question that I wanted to sort users by their likelihood of being online, and compare users according to how frequently they view the site.

Answer (score 3):

Although I asked this question myself, I now realize that such a feature would probably not be necessary: There's already a "Seen:" field on each user page that tells whether or not a user is currently online, [as described here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4445/is-there-a-way-to-identify-whether-users-are-online-or-not). If the "Seen:" field matches the current time, it indicates that the user is currently online.